# Secondary snubber in flyback converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, oscillation, snubber, switching-transients

I am designing a flyback converter.
Input = 180-240 Vac
Output = 15 V, 0.4 A

The secondary output seems to be oscillating when the diode is turns on. Oscillating frequency is around 27 MHz.
I am using TNY267 Ic for the converter.

Primary inductance = 3.3 mH.
Secondary  = 19.526 uH

I have used a RCD clamp on the drain. R = 47k. C = 2nF.
Yellow - secondary , Blue - Drain voltage waveform
[image]

The drain voltage rings at 3.77 MHz but reflected secondary voltage rings at 27.7 MHz.
I have come to understand that the ringing in the secondary is caused by the capacitance of output diode oscillating with the leakage inductance of the secondary winding.

There are many sources related to design of primary snubber.
But I cannot find any design procedure for secondary side snubber. I need a solid design procedure to damp out the ringing.

Comment: _”I have used a RCD clamp on the drain. R = 47k. C = 2nF.”_ Schematic >> words. _”Yellow - secondary”_ Secondary what? Voltage? Current? Add a schematic and refer to designators.

Comment: Are you operating in CCM or DCM?

Comment: That ringing also looks like a typical scope probe response to a fast edge (with a long ground lead), so make sure it isn't just that before any design changes.

Comment: @Drummond How can i verify that??

Comment: @Navaro Operating in DCM

Comment: @FarvezFarook Try shortening the ground lead. Do you have a [short-path ground probe](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cal-test-electronics/CT3668/5029188)? If not, reducing loop area can help too, just try to run the ground lead as close to the probe body and the PCB as possible. (and go get one of those ground pins!)

Comment: @Hearth I made a diy short path ground probe and measured the signal the result was amazing. There was no oscillation(except primary drain waveform’s reflected voltage) on the secondary voltage waveform. What can we attribute this effect to ??Why does long ground leads create this phenomenon. Thank you people for the insights provided

Comment: @FarvezFarook The problem is inductance in the ground lead!